# How to convert an RGBA image to Grayscale in python?

Tags: python, opencv, rgba

I have array of shape `(height, width, 4)`, i.e., RGBA format, and I want to convert this to grayscale. The original array has RGB values as 0 and the picture is rendered completely based on the alpha values over a white background, hence the traditional ways of turning this into grayscale fail (e.g., `cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)`).

Source image:

[image: Source Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- Your image is always black-n-white;
- White is defined as a transparency;

If these things are true, then you can use the Alpha channel *directly*:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
img_gray = 255 - img[:, :, 3]

plt.imshow(img_gray, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

If you could also have colored images, then I would ask you to provide one.