# CSS: The background color of modal-box is not changing and it is not scrollable

Tags: css, background-color, scrollable

I want to change the background color of my modal-content. All code is working but background color always appears white. Also the box is not scrollable. I want to scroll it when I click inside the box.

```css
.modal {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 50px 0px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    / background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: You have a slash after `overflow: auto;` that probably prevent the next row to work.

Answer (score 0):

insted of putting overflow: auto; its better to use overflow: scroll

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to use rgb instead of rgba or vice versa.

- rgb should take 3 parameters like the following: **rgb(0, 0, 0);**
- rgba should take 4 parameters **rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);** 4th parameter is opacity.

In order to undestand the diffrence you can see the following question: [Difference between hex colour, RGB, & RGBA and when should each they be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908277/difference-between-hex-colour-rgb-rgba-and-when-should-each-they-be-used/40908439)

According to the scrollable, you can use **overflow: auto;** but you can use **overflow: scroll;** in order to say you want to enable scrollable model implicitly.

For more information about overflow property: [CSS overflow Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)